# What is the effect of access modifiers on extension functions?

Tags: function, kotlin, extension-methods, access-modifiers, extension-function

What will happen if I change the access modifier of an extension function to `private`? Does it have any effect? Does it matter?!

**`private`** `fun String.myExtensionFunction() { // ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension method will only be seen in the class/file it is declared in.

Without private the extension method would be public and could be called from the outside.